# How to filter HTML src tags of img (and other tags) in CSS (maybe via regex)?

Tags: html, css, regex

I have an HTML source code with some `<img src="...">` tags and want to perform a CSS invert on them, but only when they have a specific url prefix in the `src="..."` tag (eg. prefix: "https://somewebsite.com/img/idx" with `idx` being the index of each image on the site). First I thought about doing some regex, but I could not make it work.

The resulting code snippet should look something like this:

```
.img(with some url prefix) {
 filter: invert(100%) !important;
}
```

As of now I could not find a solution to this problem and hence, wanted to ask if you might have an idea to solve this issue.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you add some examples so that we understand what you are talking about?

Comment: `img[src^="url-start"]`

Comment: @InSync eg. on the site [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young%27s_inequality_for_products) are some Latex equations which all have a prefix of "https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/" with some idx at the at the end. Now I want to change the color / invert of only of these images with the specified prefix. I have already managed to do it with with img {filter: invert(100%) !important;} but this changes all images, which is not intended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do something like so:

```
img[src^="https://somewebsite.com/img/idx"] {
    filter: invert(100%) !important;
}
```